# How to infer type from query in RTK Query?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

How to infer the type of the data coming from the query so that, I can have autocompletion in VS Code when populating my UI?
I have been having a look at the content in the official docs but I was not able to understand how to do it,

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery

Code below:

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

interface WeatherQuery {
    lat: Number | null;
    lon: Number | null;
    appid: string
}

export const coordQueryApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'coordQueryApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/'}),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getCurrentPositionWeather: builder.query<any,WeatherQuery>({
            query: (arg) =>{
                const {lat, lon, appid} = arg
                return {
                    url: '/weather',
                    params: {lat, lon, appid}
                }
            }
        })
    })
})

export const { useGetCurrentPositionWeatherQuery } = coordQueryApi
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you want to infer `coordQueryApi` ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to infer the return type. At the moment I am using ‘any’ type instead

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine In my case I would like to infer `coordQueryApi` since I have wraped `createApi` inside a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the type for the query result manually like this:

```js
interface CurrentPositionWeatherResult {
  propA: string;
  propB: string;
}

getCurrentPositionWeather: builder.query<CurrentPositionWeatherResult,WeatherQuery>({
```

Basically, it is not possible to refer to the external API type directly. You need to check the API's definition or specification and define the type yourself. Some API might provide their type definition code or a client library for calling their API, and in that case, you can import the type and assign it directly.